# Multiclass Changepoint detection in R

Tags: r

The output of my classification predictive model is as follows:

```
a <- c(1,1.1,1,1,2,0.9,1.1,1,1.1,1) ## Class A
b <- c(2,2.1,1.9,1.7,2,2,3,2,2,2)   ## Class B
c <- c(3,3,3.1,3.6,3.2,2,3.1,3,3,3) ## Class C
x <- data.frame(c(a,b,c))
x$color <- rep(c("red","green","blue"),times=c(10,10,10))
```

[image: Class Prediction]

I am trying to find out at which position the class type changes. In this scenario, the class type changes at positions 11 and 21.

I have tried the following packages : `CPM, EPC, QCC` but it is not giving me what I desire.

What's the best way to detect that the class type has changed?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
library(strucchange)
( bp <- breakpoints( x[, 1] ~ 1) )
#    Optimal 3-segment partition: 
# 
# Call:
# breakpoints.formula(formula = x[, 1] ~ 1)
# 
# Breakpoints at observation number:
# 10 20 
# 
# Corresponding to breakdates:
# 0.3333333 0.6666667 

bp$breakpoints
# [1] 10 20
```

([via](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26140/r-function-breakpoints-finds-more-breaks-than-fstats))